# How to update specific DataTable cells using Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a **Datatable** and I want to change the cell value of a specific column using toggle modal with input on it, on the first update it's okay but when I try to changed another row cell, the first cell that I edited also change values.

here is my code

```
 $('#Receiver tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {

                   var cell = receivertable.cell(this);

                   $("#myModal6").modal('show');
            
                   $("#savebtn").click(function () {
                       var qtyinput = $("#qtytb").val();
                       cell.data(qtyinput).draw();
                   });
                });
```

Comment: It's likely your modal only has one `savebtn` - so each time you edit a new row, you get another click handler on that button.  Change `$("#savebtn").click` to `$("#savebtn").one("click",` - alternatively move the `savebtn.click` handler outside of the td click handler so that it's only defined/run once and then change the code to handle/store the selected cell.

Comment: Note also that if you're using datatables.js then changing the HTML won't change the underlying data stored by datatables, so any paging/sorting will lose your changes